# How can I have flexible PartialView?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have the following `TextBoxFor` in my `CreateOrEdit` view:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString(),
            new {@readonly = true, @class = "form-control"})
```

Of course I can't use it like that because I get the following error:

> Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

So I changed my code like this:

```
@{
    var m = Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString();
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => m, new {@readonly = true, @class = "form-control"})
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date)
}
```

Now it doesn't give me the above error anymore and it works with Edit action because I have already a Model instance so the following line is correct in the Edit action method but not in the Create action method:

```
var m = Model.Date.Value.ToShortDateString();
```

My problem is when I use the Create action method since I have not the Model instance already I get the exception. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Date, "{0:d}", new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control"})`

Comment: But why are you not passing a default instance of your model to the view in your `Create()` method anyway?

Comment: @StephenMuecke ToShortDateString was just an example. Exactly I want to use an extension method here.

Comment: What extension method?

Comment: @StephenMuecke My own extension method that I wrote to convert the date to another culture date format.

Comment: What are you wanting to display (and you should be passing a default instance of your model in the `Create()` method anyway)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't get what's your mean. Please show an example of how can I pass a default instance of my model in the Create() method?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133314/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-user5032790).

Comment: you can do this way: if (Model.Date!=null) { //this case is for edit and apply 
}
else
{}

Comment: @RKSharma No I can't because I have not the Model instance already and if I doing this I get the NullReference Exception.

Comment: ohkay, I think you should send model instance like return view(new Model());

Comment: @StephenMuecke I have created my custom ModelBinder already. Thanks a lot I have fixed my issue by your suggestion. It will be great if you post an answer.

Comment: if there is any limitation (specific requirment) that you can't send the model instance then you have to check for if(model!=null) at every step if model is not null then apply textboxFor else apply TextBox()

Comment: great I also wish to see the answer

Comment: @RKSharma I don't think if it is possible to use if(model!=null), but I can use if(Model!=null) with upper case M that then I get the NullReference Exception as I said already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `NullReferenceException` in the `Create.cshtml` view will be the result of not passing a model to the view, which you should always do. In the case of a `Create()` method, just initialize and pass a new instance of your model to the view in the GET method.

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    var model = new yourModel();
    return View(model);
}
```